# Updating a button's css with a dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have tried all the following to update my button's css - the id of this button is generated dynamically as shown in the html below. There can be several buttons in the html and each button has a dynamic id, using which I want to change the css of a specific button depending on what it's id is

JS:

```
1. $('[name="radio-button-group"]').val(mapKeyStore.getValue(key)).css('background-color', 'yellowgreen');

2. $('#'+key).css({'background-color': 'yellowgreen !important', 'color': 'yellowgreen !important'});

3. $('[name = "radio-button-group"]').val(mapKeyStore.getValue(key)).css({'background-color': 'yellowgreen !important', 'color': 'yellowgreen !important'});

4. $('input[name^="radio-button-group"]').val(mapKeyStore.getVa‌​lue(key)).css('backg‌​round-color', 'yellowgreen');
```

HTML:

```
<div class="quality button-selector" ng-repeat="item in main.list track by $index">
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-prev btn-lg btn-block navigation-button-wrapper" for="{{item}}">
        <input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" id="{{item}}" autocomplete="off" value="{{item}}" ng-click="main.save(item);main.nextI(null)"> {{item}}
      </label>
        <br><br>
    </div>
```

The click that invokes the color change of my buttons happens on a different button. 
None of these seem to be working, the color does not get changed. 
Any inputs?

Comment: U use DOCUMENT and Jquery this not make sense. Provide full function list because now this not readably

Comment: I removed document to avoid any confusion

Comment: Why don't you just add/toggle a class?

Comment: add a specific class. Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: @jbutler483 can you give an example?

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="radio-button-group" class="MYCLASS"/>` You could then target using `$('.MYCLASS').css("background","tomato");`

Comment: Well that's the thing. There can be several buttons in the html and each button has a dynamic id, using which I want to change the css of a specific button depending on what it's id is.

Comment: you will use dynamic colour for all buttons aswell? can you please add an image of your current buttons and desire output?

Comment: can you make a plunkr with your code so that it will be wasy to resolve your issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
     $('input[name^="radio-button-group"]').css('background-color', 'yellowgreen');
});
```

You must include **jquery** before writing this code.

Comment: I tried this -     $('input[name^="radio-button-group"]').val(mapKeyStore.getValue(key)).css('background-color', 'yellowgreen'); Did not help

Comment: Added jquery lib link or not? Can you show whole code? Also have a look in console is there any error?

Comment: Yes, this has already been included - <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: did u check your console?

Comment: $index added at the end of first line in html, can i ask for what purpose you used it? is it a string?

Comment: Its an angularjs concept. Not a string, but makes the looping faster.